# Root system of fixed point Lie sub-algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is known that a non-simply laced simple root system can be constructed from the simply-laced root system by folding the Dynkin diagram and hence the corresponding non-simply-laced Lie algebra can be constructed by taking the fixed points of a non-trivial diagram automorphism (outer automorphism).

Now let $\theta$ be an inner automrphism of order $2$ of a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_1$ be the eigendecomposition. The subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is reductive. Now is there a way to get the root system of $\mathfrak{g}_0$ from the root system of $\mathfrak{g}$ ?

Comment: If the indices in the eigendecomposition correspond to eigenvalues, should'nt they be $1$ and $-1$ (and not $0$)? And do you mean $\mathfrak{g}_1$ (i.e. the fixed points under $\theta$) then?

Comment: If so, nice question, although I'm not sure if anything sensible can be said in general, as the roots somehow don't "see" inner automorphisms. But what examples have you looked at?

Comment: They are written additively. Here $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is the fixed point Lie Subalgebra and $\mathfrak{g}_1$ is a $\mathfrak{g}_0$ module.

Comment: I see. So what examples have you looked at?

Comment: Those non-simply-laced algebra is constructed by finite order diagram automorphism, which is not an inner automorphism.(Recall $Aut(\mathfrak{g})=Inn(\mathfrak{g})$ semiproduct $\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to the automorphism group of the dynkin diagram.)  I don't know the answer, good question. Btw, all finite order automorphisms of any simple lie algebra is classified nicely, I am not sure if that can help you.